# Compiling Gettext on Fedora 20 don't work

Tags: fedora20

I have an error when I'm trying to compile gettext on Fedora 20.

Firstly, I type make and I have this error:

```
[anthony@localhost ms-sys-2.3.0]$ make
cc -O2 -ansi -pedantic -Wall -c -I inc -D PACKAGE=\"ms-sys\" -D LOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -idirafter include-fallback -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -o obj/fat32fd.o src/fat32fd.c
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [obj/fat32fd.o] Error 127
```

Please help me!

Comment: Use gcc in your makefile unless cc is an alias of gcc. Install gcc if it isn't installed already.

Answer (score 1):

Install gcc by running yum

```
yum install gcc
```

Use gcc instead of cc in your makefile and cli